# In SQL Server how can I prevent a multi-threaded application from reading the same row twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I have a set of triggers which create an entry in an separate events table whenever they are update or deleted.  This table contains an ID, table name and the data which has been changed / deleted.

I have a multi-threaded application .NET core 3.0 application which periodically selects the record with the lowest ID, processes the data sends the processed data off to an API.  Once this has completed it then deletes the row from the table.

The problem is that the same row could be read twice by separate processes if the SELECT is completed by Process 1 and then Process 2 completes a SELECT before the DELETE has been completed by Process 1.

As the events table does not have a 'locked' column, I was hoping to complete this with some kind of row locking and WITH (readpast).  However as the SELECT and DELETE are in separate transactions, I'm not sure if this is suitable.

Any advice on how I could achieve this given the current set up, or would introducing a lock column be the ideal way?

Comment: See eg: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, and I would argue, safer way to David's suggestion is to segment your queue.

For a two process system you can segment your queue into odd and even items (based on ID) and have one process handle even items and the other - odd items.

This was you will never have a deadlock / race condition between two processes.

Example:

```
DECLARE @ProcessID INT = 0 -- 0 for "Process 1" and 1 for "Process 2"
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Queue]
WHERE ID % 2 = @ProcessID -- 2 is the number of processes
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

From the above you can see that this can be scaled to any number of processes.

**Advantages**

- Completely avoids deadlocking and race conditions.
- No requirement for atomic operations.

**Disadvantages**

- No guarantee of processing order.
- If one process stops, then half the items will not be processed.

Comment: brilliant comment! Exactly what I was looking for, in my case I have a table with follow sources, users to be followed and a multithreaded app, delimiting each thread with a processor Id to be included in the select statement does exactly what  I was expecting